# Create function which return size of table

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, dynamic-sql, psql

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sizeOfTableFunction
(
  p_tableName varchar(100)
)
RETURNS integer 
AS $$
DECLARE
  p_tableSize integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) into p_tableSize from p_tableName;
  return p_tableSize;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Function has been created properly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Execute:

```
SELECT * FROM sizeOfTableFunction('Run');
```

Output - problem with executing the function?:

```
mydb=> SELECT * FROM sizeOfTableFunction('Run');
ERROR:  relation "p_tablename" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT count(*)                  from p_tableName
                                              ^
QUERY:  SELECT count(*)                  from p_tableName
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "sizeoftablefunction" line 5 at SQL statement
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, but check if postgres supports dynamic sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sizeOfTableFunction
(
  p_tableName varchar(100)
)
RETURNS integer 
AS $$
DECLARE
  p_tableSize integer;
BEGIN
  execute 'SELECT count(*) from '||p_tableName into p_tablesize; -- this is the difference
  return p_tableSize;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

To be safe, it's better to use the `quote_ident` function, just in case your tablename contains special characters. It also gives you some protection from SQL injection.

```
execute 'SELECT count(*) from '||quote_ident(p_tableName) into p_tablesize;
```